# Сватья баба Бабариха

Tags: этимология, литература

Кто она такая — эта сватья баба? И почему Бабариха?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Интерефейс подсказывает мне, что пора ответить на свой вопрос. Ну что ж, не буду вредничать.

Переношу сюда "статью", впервые опубликованную на gramota.ru с небольшими дополнениями.

Ещё о Бабарихе.

Я над этой Бабарихой и её проделками уже лет, почитай, сорок задумываюсь. Сначала от скуки, с появлением Интернта - достаточно серьёзно. Нетипичный она персонаж, каких немного у Пушкина, непонятный ни изначально, ни после всех прочтений. Расшифровка имени, возможно, дала бы ключ к разгадке всего характера.

Когда-то я натолкнулся на расшифровку пушкинских записей народных сказок. Там и про Балду, и про Спящую Царевну немало любопытного, но про персонажей "Сказки о Салтане..." то ли ничего конкретного, то ли вообще ничего, не помню уж сейчас. Хотя сам Салтан явно восходит к арабскому султану (проникшему ещё и в тюркские), а Гвидон - к итальянскому Guido (видимо от ставшего нарицательным имени какого-то знатного римлянина, напрямую или через название исторической области вблизи Рима). А вот о такой родной Бабарихе - почти полный туман.

Год назад в инете случайно натолкнулся на такой вот текст.

> > > Очевидно, было не сохранившееся до наших дней слово бабара (или бабар), от которого и образовалось слово "бабариха", то есть "жена бабаря". Очень распространено прозвища женам по иненам мужей (Прониха, Данилиха).
> > > по данным Доктора филологических наук А. СУПЕРАНСКОЙ.

Увы, первоисточник оказался вне результатов моих поисков. Я попросил помочь посетителей "грамотного" форума - в результате были сформулированы еще две гипотезы, которые, впрочем, не слишком правдоподобны.

На всякий случай воспроизведу тезисно все известные мне утверждения в отношении сватьей бабы, представляющие какой-то интерес.

1. "Бабариха" не придумано Пушкиным. Она изредка встречается в литературе вплоть до XIX века.
2. Значение примерно то же, что в "Сказке". Вредноватая старушка.
3. Происхождение иногда связывают с "варвар", но вряд ли.
4. Бабариха - от собственного якобы украинского имени Бабар, то ли тюркского, то ли иранского происхождения, которое рассматривают как фонетический фариант слов бабр, бабур - тигр. Вряд ли. Имя такое, если и существовало, то было редчайшим.
5. Весьма вероятно, что "Бабариха"- фонетический вариант нецерковного имени-прозвища Боборыка, от основы, означающей рыбу с большой головой.
6. Другой вариант связывают с "бобылиха", но это возможно только в переносном значении, всё-таки у неё, похоже, были дети. А вот диалектное "боболиха" - неряшливая, грязная старушка - вполне подойдёт.
7. Вышеприведенная версия Суперанской. Никаких обоснований автор не приводит.  Сомнительно.
8. Известный "грамотный" форумчанин **adada** связал "бабариха" с гипотетическим баба+арь/арка, каковым словом могли бы называть повитуху. Крайне сомнительно.

Кстати о детях.
"Сватья баба" и "но жалеет он очей//старой бабушки своей" заставляют ломать голову не одно поколение доморощенных и вполне маститых серьёзных исследователей. Поэтому "до кучи" даю известные соображения, включая взаимоисключающие и даже внутренне противоречивые.

1. Бабушка - не обязательно кровная родственница во втором колене. Но если она, то помимо прямого значения "бабка по отцу или матери" (она вероятно и была бы "бабкой") может быть просто любой престарелой родственницей.
2. "Своей" здесь не добавляет ясности. Такую родственницу тоже могли назвать "своей".
3. Бабушка - ещё и мать или бабка кормилицы.
4. Сватья - совсем не "сваха". Это мать одного из супругов по отношению к родителям другого. Сейчас эти значения сильно смешались, у "сватьи" появилось второе, просторечно-разговорное значение "сваха" и наоборот. Но во времена Пушкина, похоже, до этого было ещё ой как далеко.
5. "Сватья баба" даёт абсолютный простор для домыслов. От полного синонима "сватьи" или жены свата (в обоих значениях: отец супруга сына или дочери или лицо, занимающееся сватовством), до "сватьи" во втором или даже третьем поколении, т.е. матери или бабушки сватьи.
6. Самое вкусное: анализ пушкинского текста. Даю только одну версию, наиболее для меня убедительную. Копирайты частично мои, остальное - выжимка из разных источников.

"Сватья" баба всегда поминается в связи и близости двух неудавшихся царских невест, приставленных высочайшей волей к холстам и борщам. Логично предположить, что она их мать (или менее вероятно - другая родственница). Тем более, что размякший монарх под конец отпускает всех трёх восвояси. Это вполне согласуется с версией, что "сватья баба" доводится Гвидону родной бабкой. А вот Салтану этот персонаж приходится... тёщей. Что многое, конечно, объясняет, но только не странную нелюбовь старухи к одной из своих дочерей, да ещё так высоко взлетевшей. Вариант Золушки или "стариковой дочки" тут не проходит, мы приняли, что Гвидону-то она - родная бабка. Так, может, всё-таки не совсем родная?

"Бабушкой" ей это быть не помешает. Бабушка - вообще любая престарелая родственница. А вот "сватья баба" плохо объяснима. Русские семейные термины позволяют не различать точного родства супруга по отношению к семье другого (сравните: "зять" и "невестка" употребимо по отношению ко всей семье супруга). А вот для обратных отношений всё очень регламентировано. Всякие шурины-золовки-свояченицы жестко привязаны к конкретному свойственнику (родственнику из семьи супруга).

Сестру или тётку родителя супруга вряд ли назовут тем же термином, что и жену этого родителя. Всё-таки баба - жена. Но чья? И тут возникает совершенно невероятное на первый взляд предположение. А не мать ли она первой, вероятно умершей, жены Салтана? Салтану она приходится экс-тёщей, Гвидону - этакой "внучатой мачехой" (вполне себе бабкой), по отношению к молодой царице совмещает роли свекрови и мачехи. Хуже, как говорится, быть не может, потому что некуда.

И термин "сватья баба" очень даже хорошо ложится в этот ряд. После смерти гипотетической первой жены Салтана, экс-тёща ему никто более. Только жена бывшего свата его, Салтанова, отца. В момент той, первой, свадьбы - ещё, видимо, царствующего монарха. Семьдесят седьмая вода на киселе, а не бросишь.

Сложновато, конечно, для стилизации простой крестьянской сказки, но чего только у Пушкина не бывает.

Но почему Пушкин ни словом о том не обмолвился? Выскажу совершенно уж крамольное предположение. Вся эта сказочная канитель Бабарихи и Салтана сильно смахивает на постоянные сплетни вокруг Императорской семьи, начиная с непростых отношений Екатерины и Павла. Гвидон же вполне годится на роль Александра Благословенного, Царица - любимой народом Вдовствующей Императрицы Марии Фёдоровны (жены, потом - вдовы Павла).

Все гипотетические "прототипы" этой истории к моменту написания сказки уже отошли в лучший мир, но память общества была сильнее. И общество вполне могло понять невиннейшую добрую сказку как карикатуру, к чему Пушкин, понятно, отнюдь не стремился. Некоторые совершенно явные и даже вопиющие нестыковки могли объяснить сознательным туманом автора.

А уж указание, что Гвидон - не родной внук Бабарихи, отмело бы последние сомнения. Ибо оно, это самое консервативное общество первых лет царствования Николая вполне позволяло себе почти открыто сомневаться в биологическом родстве как Павла, так и Александра со своими венценосными "отцами". Величайший из скандалов был бы обеспечен.

Comment: Во избежание недоразумений уточню, что не претендую на копирайты в отношении всех высказанных соображений. Но подозреваю, что я был первоисточником многого из высказанного, впоследствии разошедшегося по инету. Желающие легко найдут.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я знаю, сватья приходится матерью царю Салтану и свекровью - царице. Насчет того, кто такая Бабариха - сложнее. Мне приходилось читать интересную теорию о том, что словом "бабарь" ("баварь") (а по логике Бабариха - жена некоего бабаря") когда-то на Руси называли одно из племен мавров. То есть, выходит, что мужем Бабарихи был... мавр. Но, повторюсь, это одна из версий, которая мне попадалась. Не поручусь за ее подлинность.

Comment: Про мавра не слышал. Добавлю в копилку.
Что касается родственных отношений, то тут сложнее. Версий много можно привести, но в первую меня очередь интересуют те, которые базируются на расшифровке понятия "сватья баба".

Answer (score 0):

В эстонском язвке есть слово vabariig (не уверен в точности наисания), что означает народное царство (не уверен в точночти перевода). Но riig - это точно царство, государство, восходящее, скорее всего, к райх (да и шведский риксдаг и эстонский риигикогу - парламент - нам тут на руку). Так что бабариха-вабарииг - это может быть народ, вассалы царя Салтана в единственном числе. Салтан не поверил в невиновность жены, и он наказан одиночеством, с ним только ткачиха, повариха да наша героиня в качестве народа (как одна крепостная девка Палашка у Мироновых в Капитанской дочке. А у Гвидона многолюдно: и царевна-лебедь, и сорок витязей с Черномором, и слуги белку стерегут...
Как могло это эстонское слово прийти в русский язык? Да сколько там от Эстляндии до Михайловского! Тем более, что русский язык к такого рода заимствованиям очень даже склонен (ср. исполать - от испола эти деспота).
Но это так, публицистика...

Comment: vabariik - республика. Отсылка к шведскому для меня сомнительна, все-таки язык совершенно другой семьи.