# Имена в "Сказке о царе Салтане"

Tags: этимология, литература

Являются ли реальными имена в "Сказке о царе Салтане" или Пушкин выдумал их сам? И почему отнюдь не восточный царь носит имя, явно произошедшее от "Султан"? И есть ли реальное имя Гвидон?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не могу найти ссылок, хотя уже несколько раз отвечал на подобные вопросы на разных форумах. Найду - дам. Пока очень кратко.

Все сказочные - и не только - имена у Пушкина всегда реальные (исключение - Фарлаф, это имя сконструировано из двух реальных). Хотя иногда имя может в языке-источнике не быть и именем собственным (Наина - имя  нарицательное). При этом Пушкин не особо заботился о соответствии имени типажу героя.

Осюда и Салтан (Солтан) - казалась бы явный намек на Восток. Но на самом деле - очень косвенный. Подобные имена фигурировали в народных преданиях без всякой привязки к восточным корням.  Аналогичная история произошла с Русланом, именем изначально осетинским (по другой версии - вайнахским), но превратившемся в русском в Еруслана.

Гвидон - итальянское Гвидо (Guido), имя довольно известное.
Буян - такое название носит какой-то остов в Белом, кажется, море, но мне не известно, что было раньше, сказка или название. С другой стороны на роль прообраза Буяна претендуют несколько островов, безымянных и с другими названиями, самый подходящий - в Черном море, недалеко от Керчи.
Черномор - герой многих преданий, изначально - весьма злой персонаж, предположительно исходно связан не с морем, а с мором.
Лебедь - возможное дохристианское имя (вспоминается мифологическая сестра основателя Киева), но тут скорее всего имеется в виду нарицательное значение, хотя и не без намека.

Кого забыл? Пишите.

Касательно Бабарихи - см. мой вопрос. Сейчас ссылку дам. 
[Вот](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2283/%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0)

Comment: Про Бабариху помню! Очень интересное было обсуждение!

Comment: Ну, и зачем Пушкину было конструировать имя Фарлаф, если оно знакомо с детства каждому, кто открывал книжки по русской истории. Просто учебники и хрестоматии.Итак:
"Итак, первое упоминание имен русов было в 907 году, когда Олег послал своих людей, после разорения окрестностей Царьграда, в столицу греков для переговоров: «Олег же, немного отойдя от столицы, начал переговоры о мире с греческими цесарями Леоном и Александром и послал к ним в столицу Карла, ФАРЛАФА, Вермуда, Рулава и Стемида со словами: «Платите мне дань».». "Повесть временных лет."

Comment: Следующий эпизод: «В год 6420 (912). Послал Олег мужей своих заключить мир и ряд между греками и русскими, и послал, говоря: «Согласно другому уряжению, бывшему при тех же цесарях — Льве и Александре. Мы от рода русского — Карлы, Инегелд, ФАРЛАФ, Веремуд, Рулав, Гуды, Руалд, Карн, Фрелав, Руар, Актеву, Труан, Лидул, Фост, Стемид — посланные от Олега, великого князя русского… »(Там же)

Comment: источник?,

Comment: Прочесть эти выдержки можно например, у Иловайского. Там тема имен русов и славян развита довольно широко.А что б не шариться долго: http://www.library.by/portalus/modules/rushistory/readme.php?subaction=showfull&id=1160975552&archive=&start_from=&ucat=14&category=14

Answer (score -2):

Естественно ни Салтан ни Гвидон ни Еруслан никакие не восточные имена. Осетины потомки венедов. Имя Руслан - Рус-лан русское (венедское). Лебедь - понятно.
Это миф. герои боги. Царевна лебедь - Лада. Гвидон-Перун скорее всего и т.д. 
Три девицы - пряхи судьбы .
остров буян- волшебный райски остров (см. кельт мифологию) Сама мать Гвидона скорее всего Макошь - пряха мировой судьбы, космоса. 
Всея информация есть в многочисленной литературе 19 века рус. и иностранной.